# Competition between substitution and elimination (uni- or bimolecular)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Whats is/are the main product/s of the following reaction:

[image]

I think the main product would be the one obtained by $S_N2$, and then the one pair of enantiomers obtained by $E2$. Is $E1$ with subsequent rearrangement possible?

Comment: I believe that E1 mechanism is not possible, as there is a good base present and reaction is carried out in diluted base on room temperature.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Marko improved the typesetting of your formulae with MathJax, for more information on how to do so yourself, check out the [help], [this meta post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/7475) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444/7475).

Comment: "E2 gives enantiomers" - are you sure? Draw that molecule in the chair conformation.

Comment: Jan, thank for the welcome. @orthocresol If you take the beta-proton from the left side, or the beta proton from the right side, you get two products, which are enantiomers.

Comment: Oh, ok, my bad :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an $\mathrm{E1}$ mechanism, we would need to generate a carbocation. Our halide is attached to a secondary carbon so the generated carbocation would be secondary. A quick check of neighbouring stabilising groups is negative. And as a professor of mine once put it (possible slightly oversimplified but with some general truth in it):

> Exactly one secondary carbocation exists and that is the prop-2-yl cation.

Thus, $\mathrm{E1}$ is not possible since the carbocation will not form in any measurable amounts. For the same reason, $\mathrm{S_N1}$ is not an option. For everything else, let’s consider the molecule’s 3D structure:

[image]

The *tert*-butyl group acts as a conformation ‘anchor’ meaning that the other chair form is not viable. Luckily, bromine is pointing upwards, which gives us access both to $\mathrm{S_N2}$ and $\mathrm{E2}$ mechanisms without having to invert or use a boat conformation.

Our base/nucleophile is methanolate which is both a good enough base and a good enough nucleophile, able to access both pathways. The centre for nucleophilic attack is also well accessable. If I had to choose, I would indeed go with your choice of saying the main products will be $\mathrm{S_N2}$ adduct and two enantiomers of elimination product will also be formed. (They stem from either abstracting the proton I drew or the enantiotopic proton on the back half of the six-membered ring.)

Comment: @UrosTodorovic Glad to be of assistance ^^